# How to trigger cloudwatch events when there are scheduled maintenance on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Once in a while we receive notifications on the "Personal Health Dashboard", indicating that there are scheduled outage on some of our ec2 instances due to maintenance.

There is a link on creating cloud watch events from that dashboard but,I'm not able to see any guide to do it.

My goal is to enable email notification to several people whenever any maintenance is scheduled by aws.

Is there a way to do this?
Maybe I missed the docs detailing this, please let me know if such exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for a guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/cloudwatch-events-health.html